# Hide all elements that don't have class matching selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a cool interface to build.

There's a horizontal scrolling div containing "tiles" of images, and a radio button under each. A user will scroll and decide on an image, then click it. The radio button checks, and jQuery shows another horiz scrolling div below, "now select subcategory"... The user can then further refine the selection by choosing another "tile". That's the process complete.

The problem is I'm not sure how to hide all the elements in the 2nd tier of selection if they don't have a class that matches that of the first selection. Sounds confusing maybe. Here's some simplified HTML, I've posted it on jsfiddle to save space here. http://jsfiddle.net/RTGC3/

So in summary, you'll see from the HTML what needs to happen. A user will see categories, when they click a category, subcategories without the same id as the clicked parent category will be hidden. All others will remain visible ready for the containing div to "show".

I hope I've explained the problem well enough. Thanks for any help offered.

Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type=radio][name="type"]').live('change', function() {
       var className = $(this).parent().attr("class");
       var clsID = className.split('_')[2];
       var subID = "in_cat_" + clsID;
       $("div[class*=in_cat]").hide();
       $("div." + subID).toggle("slow");
   });
});
```

This is the JSFiddle Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/RTGC3/3/

Comment: Hi, I think I oversimplified the code I posted. I've posted the full code here, can you show me how your code would need to be adjusted to work with the full unedited code here: http://jsfiddle.net/CKrLX/1/ Thanks, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Due to your code is changed, i have to change code but now its done:
I have updated your jsfiddle. Please check this link:   http://jsfiddle.net/CKrLX/2/

Answer (score 1):

Easiest if you name both container divs with id 1 for example to the same thing, so you would have TWO class="cat_id_1".

Then something liek this:

```
$('#cat-container div input').on('change', function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    $('#des-container div.'+id).fadeToggle();
});
```

and in CSS you have display:none; on all divs in #des-container (for starters). This will listen for the radio button when it changes, first change it will call .fadeToggle() on div with matching class in your second row and show it, and second change will hide it again.

Was this what you wanted?

Actually I assuem you want all items in the second row to be displayed, but when checking a radio box you want to hide everything besides the one matching the id of the radiobutton? Then you could do like this:

```
 $('#des-container div'+id).addClass('show');
 $('#des-container div').not('div.show').fadeToggle();
```

So basically you add a class to the objects you decide to show, and hide everything that doesn't have that class. Ofcourse for this to work the other way (if you uncheck a radio-box) you would need to add a if-statement seeing the radio button that was changed was changed to checked or unchecked, if unchecked you just remove the class "show" from the element.

Comment: Hi, You're right. The 2nd tier of selection is already hidden and is shown on change of the 1st tier. When they select a category, ALL subcategories are shown currently, I need to hide all categories that don't match, so when the containing div shows, it only contains the matches sub categories. I'll work with your code, see where I get. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok, I still think you need to apply a class (or something) on shown items, cause the above code won't support more then one radiobutton checked.

Comment: Yes, If I can apply a class "show" on elements which match, that'd be perfect. I can set them all to display none by default.

Comment: Just a thought when I was making a example i Jfiddle, since you're using radio buttons instead of checkboxes you only want One category to be displayed at one time? If so, http://jsfiddle.net/vU462/